# ssh PIV error "sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "Public key for Digital Signature": agent refused operation"

Tags: ssh, yubikey

I had to recently rebuild my laptop.  In the process, I switched from Fedora31 to Kubuntu 20.04 LTS.  Everything in the switch went without a hitch, except for one thing.  Where I work we use 2FA for all logins, and utilize a yubi key for this purpose.  I thought I had everything set-up correctly, but whenever I try to ssh to a server now (and use PIV) I get this error...

```
Enter passphrase for PKCS#11:  Could not add card
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libykcs11.so": agent refused operation
```

Now, every time I reboot the system, etc I have to re-add the card as normal.  This shows that it was properly added already.

```
ssh-add -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libykcs11.so 
Enter passphrase for PKCS#11: 
Card added: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libykcs11.so
```

Despite this, it's still throwing that annoying error at me.  Now I CAN just manually enter my PW and hit the Yubi and log in.  So it's not a show-stopper.  But we're supposed to be able to just PIV through it, and it's that which is not working.  Annoying.

Thought I had everything set-up correctly, but I guess not.  On the old build (prior to rebuild) I did a complete export of all private and public keys, and trusts.  On the new system I imported those private & public keys, and the trusts file.  I also copied over my ssh configs, etc.

After a TON of Googling, I tried all the remedies I could find, including verifying ownership and permissions on the cert file itself.  To my knowledge, this is all correct.

```
-r--------  1 REDACTED_USER REDACTED_USER  1537 Jan 20  2020 id_rsa-cert.pub
```

If I do a "ssh-add -l" I do see the proper signature there.

```
ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:<<REDACTED>> Public key for Digital Signature (RSA)
2048 SHA256:<<REDACTED>> Public key for PIV Attestation (RSA)
```

While I redacted it here, I did verify that the sha256 value for the key does match with the servers in question.

So obviously, the problem is a user-induced config issue on my laptop.

Anyone have any thoughts on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your key has restricted permissions:

```sh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert
```

Comment: Ownership and permissions of the cert files is already correct.  I verified again today.  Doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Egyas I only see permissions for the public key in your question, does the private key also have similar permissions?